# How do I properly add Chromium to my Yocto linux distribution

Tags: raspberry-pi, chrome, arm, yocto

Built **Yocto** (Poky fido branch) linux distro for **Raspberry Pi 2** following this excellent tutorial [Part 1](http://www.embarcados.com.br/raspberry-pi-2-qt5-yocto-parte-1/).

Now trying to run Chromium.

Added [meta-browser](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-browser/) to my `bblayers.conf`

Added `chromium` recipes to my `.bb` image file.

Was able to compile and build my image but getting these errors when trying to run:

```
root@raspberrypi2:/usr/bin/chromium# ./chrome
[527:527:0624/195537:FATAL:browser_main_loop.cc(161)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Aborted
```

#### --no-sandbox

```
root@raspberrypi2:/usr/bin/chromium# ./chrome --no-sandbox
[528:528:0624/195641:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(164)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
[528:528:0624/195641:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(210)] Gtk: cannot open display: 
root@raspberrypi2:/usr/bin/chromium# [530:530:0624/195641:ERROR:image_metadata_extractor.cc(111)] Couldn't load libexif.
[530:530:0100/000000:ERROR:zygote_linux.cc(587)] write: Broken pipe
^C
```

#### DISPLAY=:0.0

```
root@raspberrypi2:/usr/bin/chromium# export DISPLAY=:0.0 && ./chrome --no-sandbox
[531:531:0624/195652:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(164)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
[531:531:0624/195652:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(210)] Gtk: cannot open display: :0.0
root@raspberrypi2:/usr/bin/chromium# [533:533:0624/195652:ERROR:image_metadata_extractor.cc(111)] Couldn't load libexif.
[533:533:0100/000000:ERROR:zygote_linux.cc(587)] write: Broken pipe
^C
```

#### --use-gl=egl

> *I'd be very interested to have it working with hardware acceleration*

```
root@raspberrypi2:/usr/bin/chromium# export DISPLAY=:0.0 && ./chrome --no-sandbox --use-gl=egl 
[534:534:0624/195901:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(164)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
[534:534:0624/195901:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(210)] Gtk: cannot open display: :0.0
root@raspberrypi2:/usr/bin/chromium# [536:536:0624/195901:ERROR:image_metadata_extractor.cc(111)] Couldn't load libexif.
[536:536:0100/000000:ERROR:zygote_linux.cc(587)] write: Broken pipe
^C
```

Any pointers are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps....from my "ps"  slightly different platform.

```
  /bin/sh /usr/bin/google-chrome  


2009 root      2424 S    {google-chrome} /bin/sh /usr/bin/google-chrome
2010 root      378m S    /usr/bin/chrome/chrome --use-gl=egl --user-data-dir=/home/root/.chromium/
2012 root      1956 S    /usr/sbin/chrome-devel-sandbox /usr/bin/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --user-data-dir=/home/  
2013 root      100m S    /usr/bin/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --user-data-dir=/home/root/.chromium/
2016 root      108m S    /usr/bin/chrome/chrome --type=zygote --user-data-dir=/home/root/.chromium/
2069 root      212m S    /usr/bin/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --use-gl=egl --enable-deferred-image-decoding --lan
2078 root      175m S    /usr/bin/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --use-gl=egl --enable-deferred-image-decoding --lan
```

This was launched from a desktop icon "/bin/sh /usr/bin/google-chrome" which in turn set all the variables seen in the following threads.